# Backspace a String in text file in python

Tags: python, string, parsing, text, split

I'm trying to convert a text file to Excel . I want to know if there is a way to convert

```
REQUESTING PHYSICIAN:
XYZ.

to 

REQUESTING PHYSICIAN:XYZ
```

My input is a .txt file and output is an excel file.
Thanks,
Meera

Comment: Cannot help without seeing the code you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all your strings to have their trailing dot removed and all new lines too, you can do the following:

```py
>>> a = "REQUESTING PHYSICIAN:\nXYZ."
>>> print(a)
REQUESTING PHYSICIAN:
XYZ.
>>> a = a.replace('\n', '').rstrip('.')
>>> print(a)
REQUESTING PHYSICIAN:XYZ
```

`replace()` does replace, as it names says, `'\n'` in favor of `''` (empty string) and `rstrip()` removes `'.'` on the right side of the string.